# Logged in user gets another navigation as an unregistered user

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I do website as homework to school and I want to do something like different navigation menu for register user. So If user is not logged, he will see navigation menu with Home, Log in, Register. But if he log in to system, he gets another navigation menu with his functions (for example My account, my team,... etc). I don´t know, how can I do it. I thought, that it would be via ngIf, but I don´t know how. Thanks for your help.

nav.component.html:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{ appTitle }}</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/login">Prihlasenie</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/register">Registracia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

nav.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  appTitle = 'Fantasy liga';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>

<section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

Comment: `*ngIf` sounds like a viable option, so what have you tried to achieve this? :)

Comment: I don´t know how can I use ngIf with NodeJs. Becouse from collections I get informations about user and I can identify, If he is admin or classic user. But how can I do it with angular + nodejs ... I don´t know, and it is my question for help.

Comment: Well, when you login (where apparently you get a user role as well from my understanding). Store the user somewhere in frontend, depending on your requirements you can use just a shared service if that will suffice. Then use for example `*ngIf` to show content based on the user logged in/role status. That is one option :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) but what does mean "shared service" in angular/nodejs?

Comment: This is the component interaction section, where mentioned about parent-child relationship, don't mind that, since the idea is the same, store the logged in state in a service from where components gets the logged in status. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: thank you :) I will try it and if I will some questions about this implementation, I will write here.

Comment: You are very welcome, yes, try implementing and if you run to a specific issue, then present that :) Good luck and happy coding!